# How to remove a specific route from a mounted engine in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-engines

In my routes.rb file I have mounted engine routes.

```
mount SomeEngine::Engine => '/', as: 'some_engine'
```

It adds this route:

```
match '*path' => 'redirects#show',
  constraints: SomeEngine::RedirectConstraint.new,
  via: 'get'
```

What this route does is that it catches all unknown URLs and passes them to `SomeEngine::RedirectConstraint`

I don't need that kind of functionality. Is it possible to remove that route from main app? I don't have an access to engine. Actually I need to add some routes after that engine and now they can't be reached because of `match '*path'` route.

Comment: Ideally, all the routes must be defined before mounting any engine in the routes. Did you try that?

Comment: @Sarcastic The route I want to add is almost the same. It has to catch all unknown URLs and RENDER appropriate pages. The engine route catches all unknown URLs and REDIRECT to appropriate pages. I need to get rid of that engine route because my route should be in the end of the routes file. I can't add it before engines. It will catch all URLs. it looks like this `get ':slug', format: false`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails routes: **The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.** This may help you.